# Puppet-Agent fails to resolve RPM from YUM-Repo

Tags: rpm, puppet, yum

I´m trying to resolve RPMs additional from an our own YUM-Repository. I declared the additional Yum-Repo in "/etc/yum.repos.d/" and running the command "yum install JDK-jdk.x86_64" the rpm installs succesfully.

But when using the following manifest from Puppet, Puppet doesn`t seem to look in the declared additional YUM-repository:

```
class tomcat7_rhel {
  package { "sun-JDK-1.6.0":
    ensure => latest,
    require => Yumrepo["JDK-jdk.x86_64"]    
    #require => Package["JDK-jdk.x86_64"]    
  }
}
```

Running the agent with:

```
puppet agent --test --environment det
```

the Error looks as follows:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Invalid relationship: Package[sun-JDK-1.6.0] { require =>
>   Yumrepo[JDK-jdk.x86_64] }, because Yumrepo[JDK-jdk.x86_64] doesn't
>   seem to be in the catalog Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Currently I´m completly stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define the Yumrepo? It is likely that that definition is not included in your manifests.
You should have something like this:

yumrepo {"JDK-jdk.x86_64":
  params => kdkdkd
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try requiring a yum update on package installation to make sure you're getting your latest additions:

```
exec {"yum_update":
  command => "yum update -y",
}

package { "sun-JDK-1.6.0":
    ensure => latest,
    require => [ Yumrepo["JDK-jdk.x86_64"], Exec["yum_update"] ],
}
```

Comment: I just still got the same problem ;). I tried it with "yum clean all" instead of "yum update -y" as well, I declared a Yumrepo via puppet, I set a proxy via puppet, I set a systemwide-proxy, I restartet the agent-server... but I still got the same Problem. It seems that Puppet just ignores my additional Yum-Repo.

Comment: if you do a "yum search sun-JDK" do you see the package listed?

Comment: thx for your help. The problem was sitting in front of the computer ;). I'm new to puppet and I just completly misunderstood nearly everything in the manifest :). That way it works now:

Comment: `class tomcat7_rhel {
  
  include tomcat7_rhel::my_repo  
  
  exec { "det-proxy":
    command => "/bin/bash -c export http_proxy=http://det-proxy.lala.de:3128/",
    cwd => "/etc/puppet",  
  }
  
  exec { "yum_clean":
    command => "/usr/bin/yum clean all",
    cwd => "/etc/puppet", 
  }
  
  package { "JDK-jdk":
    ensure => latest,
  } 
  
  package { "apache-tomcat-puppet-tomcat":
    ensure => latest,
    require => [Package["JDK-jdk"], Exec["yum_clean"], Exec["det-proxy"], Yumrepo["MyRepo"]], 
  }}`